# How to verify LDAP username and password via an authenticated connection?

Tags: ldap, opendj

Currently, I have 1 user have the permission to bind OpenDJ server. Then I need to verify the username and password from the end user. How can I do that?

This is the way I create the LDAP connection and bind successfully:

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection("opendj.mydn.com.vn");
//Set session options
connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
connection.Bind(new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypassword"));
```

After that, I need to use this connection to verify the `"user1"` and `"password1"`.

How can I query this action?

This is the configuration of OpenDJ:

```
Host_LDAP=opendj.mydn.com.vn
dn_LDAP=ou\=People,dc\=mydn,dc\=com
#uid_LDAP=uid\=webservice,ou\=People,dc\=mydn,dc\=com
uid_LDAP=webservice
admin_LDAP_verify_attr=uid
admin_LDAP_verify_dn=ou\=People,dc\=mydn,dc\=com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already done it. If the bind succeeded, the username and password were correct.

**EDIT** Your 'IT guy' is seriously misinformed. According to the [OpenDJ configuration documentation #6.1.5](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/admin-guide/#aci-required), there is no real 'bind' permission. Instead:

> Bind
>
> Because this is used to establish the user's identity and derived authorizations, ACI is irrelevant for this operation *and is not checked.* To prevent authentication, disable the account instead. For details see Section 11.2, "Managing Accounts Manually".

[Emphasis added.]

Comment: Thank bro, but I need use this connection to verify another user (user1)

Comment: So you need to bind as that user, with his password. Bind is the critical step here.

Comment: The IT guy told me that only myuser is granted permission to bind to this OpenDJ. After that I, need use my user to verify other users.

Comment: It appears that the IT guy doesn't know what he's talking about. Any LDAP user must be able to bind as himself. Otherwise it is misconfigured.

Comment: I tried to bind by user1 but not successful. I have updated my question to add LDAP configuration. The IT guy just provides this info and 1 user (myuser) to verify others user. I have searched for 1 day but could find the solution. :(

Comment: I've given you the solution. I dont know what else you want. If your IT guy doesn't understand LDAP, get one who does.

Comment: Thank you, bro. I will ask him to grant permission to each user to bind

Comment: See edit. You don't have to do anything, IT guy notwithstanding, but he needs to read his product documentation, and to stop wasting developers' time. If you can complain about this without self-harm I would do so.

Comment: Thank you very much. It saves my life